# How to show children when clicking on a TreeNode in GWT

Tags: gwt, tree, treenode

I'am using a CellTree to display data from a dataProvider. Actually I display the children of a node by clicking on the arrow. Is there a way to do so by clicking on the the node it self ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory only, I'm afraid there's no *easy* way. You'd have to start from the [root node](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTree.html#getRootTreeNode%28%29) and [walk down](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/TreeNode.html#getChildValue%28int%29) until you find the selected value. You can safely use `setChildOpen(index, true)` here to walk down the tree, because clicking on a tree node means all its parent are already open, so `setChildOpen` will always return the `TreeNode` for the node so you can explore its children's value).